# Tracking of delegations

Tags: c#, docusignapi

I want to track delegations of a signer when there are multiple delegations.

I already tried going via:

- Audit Events
- Carbon Copies
- Order of Signers
- ID's per signer

Each of these methods doesn't work properly for tracking, because:

- Audit Events: After the 2nd delegation it is unclear from which signer the delegation originates from; This also gets double hard, if 2 distinct signers delegate to the same person
- Carbon Copies: Only contain a distinct list of delegations (among others), so tracking at least 2 distinct signers that delegate to the same person is not possible
- Order of Signers: Signers are always ordered by email, therefore the order cannot be used to infer which original signer is connected to the current delegation, if the emails are not coincidentally in the same order again
- ID's per signer: All ID's change with a delegation, even the "recipientId" I intially set myself; Therefore I cannot use my own "recipientId" value to track which signer in the given order relates to my original one

I also cannot use webhooks, since we want to distribute our software to many customers, which have their own DocuSign-Account. Having every customer open a specific point in their network to the internet, just so our software can receive a webhook, is not an option we want to pursue. Both, for security of the customers network and ease of installation.

How can I track delegations if there are more than 2 delegations a signer?

Answer (score 0):

> I also cannot use webhooks, since we want to distribute our software
> to many customers, which have their own DocuSign-Account. Having every
> customer open a specific point in their network to the internet, just
> so our software can receive a webhook, is not an option we want to
> pursue. Both, for security of the customers network and ease of
> installation.

This is probably a misunderstanding of how webhooks work. They have nothing to do with your customers. They do not need to open any point in their network.
The webhook call is made from DocuSign servers, to your own server. It normally doesn't require network work if you use a cloud service, but if you want to use your own (not your customers'!) server then yes, you may need to get your IT dept to open the ability of DocuSign servers to call you.

Using webhooks is highly recommended ,so I suggest you go back to looking into this.

Comment: No, I'm fully aware how webhooks work. Our product runs locally on the customers computer without a server from us being called or anything. So, the product runs on the customers computer and on the customers DocuSign account. Therefore, the DocuSign account of the customer needs to know some URL leading to our product, which runs on their network. Which leads to the problems I outlined. I would like to use them, but it's simply not currently feasable.